# wpf listview argumentoutofrangeexception in mscorlib

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, exception

I have a listview in a simple wpf application, and  it throws an unhandled exception: http://www.picz.ge/img/s2/1407/6/4/4d2baa8909d8.png

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
 Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
 and less than the size of the collection.**

I can't understand where is the mistake.
when I set `time=2000;` code works fine;
here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Wpftemp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Thread t;
        List<Something> listview_source;
        int time;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listview_source = new List<Something>();
            listview.ItemsSource = listview_source;
            t = new Thread(f);
            time = 100;
            t.Start();
        }

        private void f()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                listview_source.Clear();
                refreshe_source();
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( delegate()
                {
                    listview.Items.Refresh();
                });
                Thread.Sleep(time);
            }
        }
        private void refreshe_source()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
            {
                 listview_source.Add(new Something(DateTime.Now.Second));
            }

        }

        struct Something
        {
           public Something(double i)
            {
                this.i = i;
            }
           double i;

           public double var
           {
               get { return i; }
               set { i = value; }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your intention? as this all looks like a bad idea.

Comment: I wanted to write a task manager

Comment: The trick is with WPF is to NEVER touch a control in the code, instead replace your `List<T>` with `ObservableCollection<T>` and bind that to your `ListView`, and just add and update the `ObservableCollection` and any changes will be shown in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in Using Dispatcher because the code inside dispatcher.Invoke() will be executed after the Main Thread is ready to execute it, so it is not guaranteed when exactly the code inside Dispatcher.Invoke() will be executed, so when you increased the value of time you guarantee that the code has been executed. Remove Dispatcher or Increase the value time.

Comment: and how to access listview without dispatcher?

Comment: You can access it directly in the main thread, but you must use the dispatcher when accessing it from another thread, You can use dispatcher in Add, Refresh and Clear list items

Comment: @Wael - `code inside dispatcher.Invoke() will be executed after the Main Thread is ready to execute it, so it is not guaranteed when exactly the code inside Dispatcher.Invoke() will be executed` - This statement is completely wrong. It is synchronous so will be executed before any preceding statement. `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous which executes when Dispatcher gets time.

Comment: @RohitVats- You are right dispatcher.Invoke() is synchronous operation, BUT synchronous operation inside the Main Thread only NOT for all threads. `listview_source.Clear(); // 1`
                `refreshe_source(); //2`
                `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( delegate()
                {
                    listview.Items.Refresh(); // 3
                });`
                `Thread.Sleep(time); //4` I mean that statement 4 may execute before statement 3, but if there is another statement (5) after statement 3 and inside Invoke() method, then statement 5 MUST execute after statement 3.

Comment: No that's not true. Statement 3 will execute first always before statement 4. UI dispatcher will execute all pending operations and execute statement 3 then control will be passed to statement 4. You can try to print something in UI dispatcher using Invoke and something else in statement 4, you will see that statement 3 will execute always.

Comment: MSDN document also clearly states that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx): `Invoke is a synchronous operation; therefore, control will not return to the calling object until after the callback returns.`.